# How to install php on terminal

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache2

I'm having a problem installing PHP5 on Ubuntu. I've installed apache, but when I try to install PHP5 I get the error:

`E: package 'libapache2-mod-php5' has no installation candidate`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is better suited for AskUbuntu.com

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the multiverse repository...

`sudo apt-add-repository multiverse`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5`

Comment: i use sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5

Comment: Try `sudo apt-add-repository multiverse` first

Comment: no my ubuntu is 16.04 and the php not php5,, the php is php7,,but thank you